# How to make custom texts in jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, text, jspdf

I am using **jsPDF** and I have this text:

```
const text = 'Nisi nobis quae minus explicabo consequatur dolores blanditiis.'
```

By doing this:

```
doc.setFontSize(9);
doc.text(20,20, text);
```

I get like this:

> Nisi nobis quae minus explicabo consequatur dolores blanditiis.

But I want it to come out like this:

> Nisi **nobis quae** minus explicabo **consequatur** dolores blanditiis. // the last word with underlining

How do i do it?